# No header space for QGroupBox

Tags: c++, qt, qwidget, qgroupbox

When I add a `QGroupBox` with no title (empty string) it still occupies the space for the header. I would like to get rid of that header space and align the top of the box with the "Foo" line edit (see screenshot).

From the [Qt stylesheet docu](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/stylesheet-reference.html#title-sub) I know that I likely can use `::title`. But I have to set it with `ui->myGroupbox->setStylesheet` and `QGroupBox::title` seems not to work here.

And idea how to solve the issue?

[image: group box]

Comment: how about taking the easy way and using something more fitting as the container, e.g., `QWidget` or `QFrame`?

Comment: yes, it is a workaround I will consider if I do not find a solution. Reason why using a `QGroupBox` : I have other group boxes (with headers) in there, all using the same style. I`d like to keep that uniform.